# XPages - editing an XPages created in 8.5.3 with IBM Notes 9

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

Is it possible to edit an XPage created with IBM Notes 8.5.3 fp1 and using extension library controls with IBM Notes 9? This seems to be the cause of a problem I have.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised, but I haven't run into the issue. If you have any colleagues that have 8.5.3, I'd copy over the xml and save it in a new xpage in 9.

Comment: If you share the problem you are facing, you actually might get an answer

Comment: More important is Domino version, not Designer. And please, write what your problem is.

Answer (score 5):

Tony,
you created a XPage in 8.5.3FP1 using the Extlib and now want to alter it using a Domino Designer 9.0?
The answer yes, you can. As a save guard you want to edit your application property and set it to 8.5.3.

Comment: Problem was that changes to an XPage in Designer were not being displayed when viewing the XPage with a browser. I solved the problem by deselecting com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.library on the advanced tab of Application properties. With this option selected, it was possible to update the XPage using Designerr 8.5.3 but not Designer 9.